# blender donut NEWBIE please help

Tags: modeling, camera

[image]

anyone know how to delete the yellow and red-dotted box from the camera? I've tried ctrl+b and it still wont let me get out of it.

Comment: Do you meaning locking/unlocking the camera ? If so, for the red-dotted line, it is the check box in the panel next to the Outliner editor. Look at "View/View Lock/Lock/Camera to View". The yellow line is indicating that the Camera is the selected object. To remove it, just click on the background.

Comment: In Object Mode, Ctrl-B + drag sets a render region, which is what you appear to have, here? Ctrl-**Alt**-B clears it.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: thank you,teflancien it has fixed